# Optimizing a node search method given a 2-D spatial point

Tags: python, optimization, search, tree, numba

I have a tree-like structure called `grid`. I have designed it as a structured numpy array. Each element of `grid` is a tree-node. Each node itself is a structured numpy array, with fields that describe its bounding box (`xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax`) in 2-D space. Each node has an ID which is basically the index of that node in `grid`. Each node has a field `parent` which is the ID of its parent. Each node has a field called `children` which is a numpy array of integers containing the IDs of its children. `nChildren` obviously denotes number of children that node has (this tree is not a strict binary/quadtree). Root node has parent `ID = -1` and `-99999` is just a flag for when I want to return an integer instead of `None`.

Given below is a function, whose arguments are `(r, z)`, a spatial-point in 2-D space, `c_index` which is the node we start with, and of course, the whole `grid` object. Task is to find the smallest node given `(r, z)` and a starting `c_index` that contains the point (speaking of that, if anybody has an idea why we use squares of the `xmin` and `xmax` when checking if the point is in the cell, please tell me).

I have done profiling of the function. Without using Numba-JIT with `nopython=True`, the function takes around ~75 seconds for around ~180K calls. With Numba-JIT with `nopython=True`, it takes around ~14 seconds for around the same number of calls. That is good and all, but I desire a bit more performance as you can tell it is called an obscenely large number of times.

Here is the function:

```
def locate_photon_cell_mirror(r, z, c_index, grid):
    NMAX = 1000000
    found = False
    cout_index = c_index
    abs_z = np.abs(z)

    for j in range(NMAX):
        cout = grid[cout_index]
        if (cout['xmin']**2 <= r and
            cout['xmax']**2 >= r and 
            cout['ymin']    <= abs_z and
            cout['ymax']    >= abs_z):
            if (cout['nChildren'] == 0):
                found = True
                return cout_index, found
            
            flag = True

            for i in range(cout['nChildren']):
                child_cell = grid[cout['children'][i]]
                if (child_cell['xmin']**2 <= r and 
                    child_cell['xmax']**2 >= r and 
                    child_cell['ymin']    <= abs_z and 
                    child_cell['ymax']    >= abs_z):

                    cout_index = cout['children'][i]
                    flag = False
                    break
            
            if (flag):
                cout_index = -999999
                return cout_index, found
        
        else:
            cout_parent = cout['parent']
            if cout_parent != -1:
                cout_index = cout_parent
            else:
                cout_index = -999999
                return cout_index, found
    
    cout_index = -999999

    return cout_index, found
```

Comment: Questionable is not only _why we use squares of the `xmin` and `xmax` when checking if the point is in the cell_, but also why `abs_z = np.abs(z)` is used - to me it seems both manipulations are incompatible with the declared goal to find a _bounding box (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) in 2-D space_ of _(r, z), a spatial-point_. By the way, what are the value ranges of the coordinates, and how many nodes are there?

Comment: @Armali I am not completely sure, but this 2-D grid is assumed to symmetric the X-axis, as well as the azimuthal direction. Thereby forming a 3-D cylindrical volume. But in my program, (r, z) are always points in 2-D, in the first quadrant. So maybe the square and abs() are there to account for that?

The coordinates can be variable and spacing is not uniform (bounding boxes are smaller near origin, and bigger far away from origin as tree is refined parametrically) (parametrically initialised). For an average input, you can have around 60-70K nodes, with atmost 10K leaf nodes.

Comment: Okay - why the computation is done that way is not very important for optimization. One possibility might by to sort the nodes once (of course without losing the ID) e. g. by `'ymin'`, storing the greatest height, in order to quicker locate a containing node to start with - but it depends on the actual data. I may be able to do some experiments if you'd provide sample data.